# react-native-maps-direction package is not showing route in ios Device on map

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using [react-native-maps-directions](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions) to display route on google map, but its not showing route between two points in iOS. Working fine on Android.

Answer (score -1):

you can use react-native-maps-directions in react-native-maps to plot route from origin to destination and also have the ability to display waypoint between the origin or source to the destination